# ¿Cómo me conecto a una Base de Datos MySQL con Python?

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos

Usando una aplicación escrita en Python, ¿cómo puedo conectarme a una Base de Datos MySQL?

**Pregunta original:**

- [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) formulada por Marc Lincoln

Comment: Seria mejor mencionar lo que has intentado. -1 por no parece tener un trabajo de investigación.

Comment: @Flimzy no es mi pregunta, tendrías que hacer ese comentario en la pregunta original

Comment: La pregunta original tiene 7 años. Los estandares eran mucho más bajo entonces.

Comment: @Flimzy y sin embargo la respuesta wiki fue editada hace dos días

Comment: @CésarBustíos Una pregunta como esta es merecedora de que te pregunten ["¿Qué has intentado?"](https://medium.com/@unrob/que-has-intentado-12b31d36bc89#.wj1b8edir). Efectivamente, los estándares están subiendo, y es necesario mantenerlos. Lo primero que se lee en el centro de ayuda, en ["¿Cómo preguntar?"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) es: *Busca, e investiga*. Debe haber evidencia de un esfuerzo de parte de la persona que pregunta.

Comment: @Barranka estimado eso yo lo se de memoria. Al parecer ya se fueron por la tangente con el tema este de las migraciones desde SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Conectándose a MySQL usando Python en 3 pasos

1. **Configuración**:

   Debes instalar el driver para MySQL antes de hacer cualquier cosa. A diferencia de PHP, solo el driver para SQLite viene instalado por defecto en Python. El paquete mas usado para hacerlo es [MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) pero es un poco difícil de instalar usando `easy_install`.

   Para usuarios de Windows, pueden descargar un [exe de MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/).

   Para Linux, es un paquete casual (`python-mysqldb`). Puedes usar en la línea de comandos `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` para distribuciones basadas en Debian o `yum install mysql-python` para distribuciones basadas en RPM.

   Para MAC, puedes [instalar MySQLdb usando Macport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x#1448476).
2. **Uso:**

   Después de la instalación, reinicia el sistema. Esto no es obligatorio, pero va a prevenir que responda otras 3 o 4 preguntas si algo sale mal. Asi que, por favor, reinicia.

   Luego, es como usar cualquier otro paquete:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import MySQLdb

   db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # tu host, usualmente localhost
                        user="john",         # tu usuario
                        passwd="megajonhy",  # tu password
                        db="jonhydb")        # el nombre de la base de datos

   # Debes crear un objeto Cursor. Te permitirá
   # ejecutar todos los queries que necesitas
   cur = db.cursor()

   # Usa todas las sentencias SQL que quieras
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TU_TABLA")

   # Imprimir la primera columna de todos los registros
   for row in cur.fetchall():
       print row[0]
   ```

   Por supuesto que existen miles de posibilidades y opciones; este es un ejemplo bastante básico. Vas a tener que leer la documentación. [Un buen punto de partida](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/).
3. **Un uso más avanzado:**

   Una vez que sepas como funciona, puedes usar un [ORM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeo_objeto-relacional) para evitar escribir sentencias SQL manualmente y manipular las tablas como si fueran objetos de Python. El ORM mas famoso en la comunidad Python es [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

   Realmente te recomiendo usarlo: tu vida será mucho más fácil.

   Recientemente descubrí otra joya en el mundo de Python: [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Es un ORM bastante ligero, realmente sencillo y rápido de configurar y usar. Me ayudó mucho en pequeños proyectos o aplicaciones stand alone, donde el uso de grandes herramientas como SQLAlchemy y Django puede ser excesiva:

   ```
   import peewee
   from peewee import *

   db = MySQLDatabase('jonhydb', user='john',passwd='megajonhy')

   class Book(peewee.Model):
       author = peewee.CharField()
       title = peewee.TextField()

       class Meta:
           database = db

   Book.create_table()
   book = Book(author="me", title='Peewee is cool')
   book.save()
   for book in Book.filter(author="me"):
       print book.title

   Peewee is cool
   ```

   Este ejemplo funciona como ejemplo de usabilidad. Nada mas que tener instalado `peewee` (`pip install peewee` :-)) es requerido. Sin configuraciones complicadas. Es excelente.

### Respuesta original:

- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/688393) de wiki comunitario

---

Si estás usando una versión actual de Python, la alternativa es usar [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) el cual es un fork de MySQLdb1 y con soporte para Python 2.7 y >3.3.

**Instalación:**

Desde la línea de comandos:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

**Ejemplos:**

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
c = db.cursor()
max_price = 5
c.execute("""
    SELECT spam, eggs, sausage 
    FROM breakfast
    WHERE price < %s
""", (max_price,))
# no hay que olvidarse de liberar el cursor y la conexión para evitar fugas de memoria
c.close()
db.close()
```

Otra forma más *pythónica* de realizar la conexión es mediante el *with statement*, que se encarga de asegurar que la conexión sea correctamente liberada:

```
import MySQLdb

max_price = 5
with MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs") as conexion:
    consulta_sql = "SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast WHERE price < %s"
    parametros = (max_price,)
    cursor = conexion.execute(consulta_sql, parametros)
    for registro in cursor:
        print(registro)
```

**Enlaces:**

- [Documentación oficial](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Como aportación a wiki de comunidad es pobre, muy pobre, una traducción de una respuesta obsoleta sin preocuparse en actualizarla. En ningún momento se habla de DBAPI2, ni de la importancia de cerrar la conexión a la base de datos. Se enlaza a una librería que no tiene soporte para Python 3, y que si se mira en PyPi (con el enlace proporcionado) la última versión subida es de hace casi 2 años... En mi opinión la pregunta y la respuesta aportan más problemas que soluciones.

Comment: @tinproject pues entonces puedes ayudar a mejorarla, para eso se ha hecho el wiki. Yo agregué la última parte con la librería que tiene soporte para Python 3

Comment: @CésarBustíos si por mi fuera borraría completamente la respuesta original por demasiado amplia y desactualizada. Como ya he dicho aporta más problemas que soluciones..