# Python: ¿Cómo instalar MySQLdb en OS X?

Tags: python, macos

Tengo escritos algunos programas en Python (uso Python 2.7, pero no tendría problemas para pasarme a Python 3) para analizar una base de datos alojada en MySQL (todo en `localhost`, así que no tengo ningún problema para conectarme). Los programas funcionan a la perfección en Debian... sin embargo, necesito también ejecutar estos análisis en una computadora Mac, y me enfrento al problema de que no está disponible el módulo `MySQLdb`.

Intenté instalar este módulo con `pip` (siguiendo las instrucciones descritas [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794121/cant-install-python-mysql-on-os-x-10-10-yosemite) y [aquí también](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)) y al ejecutar mi código, me sigo topando con el mensaje `"No module named MySQLdb"`.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

---

**Actualización**

Aquí está el *output* de la consola, al intentar usar `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip install MySQL-python
Password:
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Real name of requirement MySQL-python is mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108Kb): 108Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/Users/miusuario/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Users/miusuario/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

    from setup_posix import get_config

  File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named ConfigParser

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/miusuario/.pip/pip.log
```

Y este es el contenido de `pip.log`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Tue Dec 15 15:54:01 2015
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently - Redirection to url '/simple$
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python when looking for download links for MySQL-python
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Real name of requirement MySQL-python is mysql-python
  URLs to search for versions for MySQL-python:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.4-win32.egg#md5=6620279666cb40e26d89$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.5-win32.egg#md5=596ec38e498e80ce7375$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3b1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg#md5=43ace300f3eda$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3b2-py2.5-linux-i686.egg#md5=36f78115685d8$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg#md5=1efcbed6f1f29$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3b1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg#md5=4a640ca00352a$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3b2-py2.6-linux-i686.egg#md5=08ba3e38b899a$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/M/MySQL-python/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg#md5=fd472a7c42ef8$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=313b4ceed0144a3019f8$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=e0a9f62c7a65eca79a$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b2.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=ac5812bf27dde82c41$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=4596e73263008aa83d$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=b53ad22d5a8e16d11f$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=ad3dd07e28fd38c89a$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4c1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=2a07d427814482fb90$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=6f43f42516ea26e79cfb$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz#md5=215eddb6d853f6f4be5b4afc41542$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3b1.tar.gz#md5=906c00cbfb81f54a474b3e7dcf7$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3b2.tar.gz#md5=e30ae85d490e87f3788eb4a59e5$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar.gz#md5=310dd856e439d070b59ece6dd7a$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip#md5=ddf2386daf10a97af115ffad2ed4a9a0$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b1.tar.gz#md5=138669627e06f10c1c2e75122f6$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b2.tar.gz#md5=d13f7351e195277ffd019bd7644$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b3.tar.gz#md5=b495d89426d83ba1e305f774e81$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b3.zip#md5=2fb8db45f5c71dbc5869bd19eaaf54$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.tar.gz#md5=0958cb9c23d5a656caac031c488$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.zip#md5=2ce6fad5c5fe4074c33e8e799dc7a0$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5.tar.gz#md5=2d760ee948aff4f50d01afdf8af$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5.zip#md5=4f645ed23ea0f8848be77f25ffe94a$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4c1.zip#md5=a05925412cd824104da064db6a8896$
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c$
  Using version 1.2.5 (newest of versions: 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.4c1, 1.2.4b5, 1.2.4b5, 1.2.4b4, 1.2.4b4, 1.2.4b3, 1.2.4b3, 1.2.4b2, $
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c$
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/Users/miusuario/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Users/miusuario/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

    from setup_posix import get_config

  File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named ConfigParser

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 986, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 222, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subproc$
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

De aquí deduzco (pero puedo estar equivocado) que hace falta un módulo llamado `ConfigParser`... pero al momento de intentar instalarlo, también con `pip`, esto es lo que sucede:

```
$ sudo pip install ConfigParser
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ConfigParser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Estoy perplejo... el módulo `ConfigParser` sí existe, pero al intentar instalar `MySQL-python` no lo encuentra

Comment: ¿Intentaste usando [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/)?

Comment: Buena pregunta yo alguna vez traté de realizar esto en casa, incluso instalé homebrew, no encontré forma de instalar mysqldb! =( espero una respuesta a esta pregunta! =)

Comment: ¿Podrías poner más información sobre el log?

Comment: ¿Usa `pip` el mismo Python que el que usas para escribir el script?

Comment: Hiciste lo que mencionan [acá](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/569/688)?

Comment: Pues esas instrucciones que seguiste son un peligro, porque instalan el paquete usando `sudo` http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/849/74

Comment: No queda claro con tu pregunta `pip` llegó a funcionar, coincido con @learnercys en que estaría bien que pusieras el log, tal vez en https://gist.github.com

Comment: @JonathanHernandez Sí.. efectivamente. Después intenté hacerlo con `pip` y tampoco funcionó

Comment: @learnercys Acabo de poner la salida de la consola y el log en la pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Cómo puedo verificar cuál Python es el que usa `pip`? (confieso: soy un neófito en Python... especialmente en OS X... instalar bibliotecas de Python en Debian es verdaderamente fácil)

Comment: Puedes escribir `which pip` y `pip --version` para ver la ruta y la versión, respectivamente.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que tu problema es exactamente igual a **[esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)**.

*En resumen:*

- `mysql-python` sólo funciona para la versión 2 de python y actualmente
  estás usando la versión 3.
- El modulo `ConfigParser` si existe, pero el nombre real es
  `configparser` (poner atención a las mayúsculas). Básicamente cuando haces el `pip install` se hace una búsqueda con el nombre dado y unas alternativas a él: ConfigParser, configparser, etc. Lo que no sucede cuándo haces un import (es por eso el `ImportError: No module named ConfigParser`)
- La solución es que busques una alternativa a `mysql-python`. Del
  enlace al inicio te puedes dar cuenta que la más recomendada es `mysqlclient`, lo instalas con `pip install mysqlclient` y también puedes ver algunos ejemplos **[aquí](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python)**

Answer (score 3):

`Mysql-python` solo es compatible con `python 2` ([Python3 WOS](https://python3wos.appspot.com/)), y el `pip` es de `python 3`:

```
$ which pip
```

Muy probablemente devolverá algo similar a:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.x/bin/pip
```

Para hacer la instalación bajo `python 2`, hay que seleccionar el `pip` de `python 2`:

```
$ sudo pip2 install MySQL-python
```

La otra opción es un módulo puro `python` que es compatible `python 2` y `3`, como [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL).

Al final, para evitar los conflictos de versiones y también los `python` de Apple (con varios problemas) es mejor hacer la instalación de `python 2.x` y `3.x` con `homebrew`, y utilizar [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) que permite la creacion de entornos virtuales `python`, cada cual con solo los requisitos para el entorno. Sin entornos virtuales hay que siempre ser explicito: `pip2` o `pip3` en vez de `pip`.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar

```
pip search mysql
```

y hallaras uno que es soportado. Hay problemas que desconozco por el paquete que quieres instalar y la versión de python. Pero con ello hallaras otro cliente que trabaje de la misma forma.